# PDFkit raise "command failed: #{invoke}" if result.to_s.strip.empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdfkit

I'm trying to use PDFkit.  I get

```
command failed: "/Users/burtondav/sites/ndeavor/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64" "--page-size" "Letter" "--margin-top" "0.75in" "--margin-right" "0.75in" "--margin-bottom" "0.75in" "--margin-left" "0.75in" "--encoding" "UTF-8" "--print-media-type" "--quiet" "-" "-"
```

It errors on this code in (gem) pdfkit-0.5.3/lib/pdfkit/pdfkit.rb

```
73     raise "command failed: #{invoke}" if result.to_s.strip.empty?
```

I have wkhtmltopdf-amd64 in /bin/

In pdfkit.rb, I have:

```
 config.wkhtmltopdf = Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf-amd64').to_s
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615298/pdfkit-wkhtmltopdf-broken-pipe-os-x-and-rails-3